# Specify end date for celery periodic task

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to create a periodic task in celery, but that should execute only between a start date and end date that I specify.
For example, I intend to execute the task daily from October 16, 2021 until November 10, 2021 at a fixed time. In the crontab expression, I'd specify the following

1. day_of_month = 16-31,1-10
2. month_of_year = 10,11

In this case, my requirement is that the periodic tasks should not execute after Novemeber 10. But celery triggers the task even after November 10, because I've given day_of_month from 16-31. How can this be prevented ? Is there any setting/configuration available in celery, where I can specify an end-date for my periodic tasks ?

Comment: You can create two schedules I believe, one for October and the other one for November. They would run the same task, with same parameters, but have different names. To be honest I have never tried this in the past, but it is worth a try. :) Let me know if it works so that we can write a proper answer to the question then.

Comment: Thanks @DejanLekic. This helps in solving the problem to an extent.
However, if the periodic task spans more than a year, it becomes tricky to handle the situation. For example, if the start date is October 16,2021 and end date is November 10, 2023, then the separate schedule for October and November are required only for the year 2023.

Comment: Here's another approach that I tried - Every time a trigger hits, I check if the trigger time is greater than the end date. If it is greater, then I remove/unschedule the trigger so that further triggers are not hit